# Wordpress WP_Query with offset generating an extra page in the pagination giving 404 error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I noticed the pagination is generating an extra page which gives a 404 error. How can I fix this?

I have `Settings > Reading` set to 10 posts too. Something in my code below is returning the wrong number of total posts but I can't figure out how.

PS: The offset is necessary.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
                $current_page = get_query_var('paged');
                $current_page = max( 1, $current_page );
                $per_page = 10;
                $offset_start = 4;
                $offset = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start;
                $post_list = new WP_Query(array(
                    /*'cat'            => -15,*/
                    'category'       => $category_name,
                    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
                    'paged'          => $current_page,
                    'offset'         => $offset, // Starts with the second most recent post.
                    'orderby'        => 'date',  // Makes sure the posts are sorted by date.
                    'order'          => 'DESC',  // And that the most recent ones come first.
                ));
                if ( $post_list->have_posts() ):
                while ( $post_list->have_posts() ):
                $post_list->the_post();
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span class="category">
                    <?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
                </span>
                <h2 class="card__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'total'   => $post_list->max_num_pages,
                        'current' => $current_page,
                        'type'    => 'plain',
                        'prev_text' => '«',
                        'next_text' => '»'
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php  
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```